# How to properly programmatically add field collections to an entity in drupal 8?

Tags: 8, migrations, entities

What is the proper way to programmatically add a field collection to an entity in Drupal 8?

I can't find this online.

This is what I'm using and it seems to work.  The tricky part is setting the host entity:

```
  protected function randomUnorderedListItems($profile, $count = 3) {

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

      //get definition of target entity type
      $entity_def = \Drupal::entityManager()->getDefinition('field_collection_item');

      //load up an array for creation
      $item = array(
        //use the entity definition to set the appropriate property for the bundle
        $entity_def->get('entity_keys')['bundle'] => 'field_unordered_list',
      );

      $item = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('field_collection_item')->create($item);
      $item->setHostEntity($profile, TRUE);
      $item->field_card_title->setValue($this->random->sentences(4, TRUE));
      $item->field_titled_credential->generateSampleItems(3);

      $item->save();

      $profile = $item->getHost();

    }

  }
```

Comment: The first part seems to be messy for me, the rest is totally fine!